# Fibonacci Series Using Lists?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am trying to print fibonacci series using lists in python.
This is my code

```
f=[1,1]
for i in range(8):
    f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2])

print(f)
```

output is

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8]
```

I am not getting the bug here!

Comment: Consider adding some debug output, such as what `i`, `f`, `f[i-1]`, and `f[i-2]` are on each step.

Comment: consider what happens when `i=2` - you've already appended to the list twice, but the next value you append is `f[0] + f[1]`

Comment: You are starting with the wrong list index for appending. You start with index 2 in the list, so you should also start your loop with that, i.e. `range(2, 8)`

Answer (score 3):

Python's `range` starts at 0, you need to start with generating element 2.  By starting at 0, you get negative indices for the first couple of calculations, which access from the end of the list.  To fix this, change the loop to `for i in range(2, 8)`.

To clarify what seems to be a source of confusion, by starting the `range` at zero and using negative indexing you end up with the following terms being summed and appended to the list:

```
f[2] = f[0-1] + f[0-2] = f[-1] + f[-2] (= f[1] + f[0]) = 1 + 1 = 2  # looking good
f[3] = f[1-1] + f[1-2] = f[0] + f[-1] (= f[0] + f[2]) = 1 + 2 = 3   # looking good
f[4] = f[2-1] + f[2-2] = f[1] + f[0] = 1 + 1 = 2                    # oops!
f[5] = f[3-1] + f[3-2] = f[2] + f[1] = 2 + 1 = 3
```

From that point on the numbers are on track, but offset from the proper indexing by 2.

Comment: Maybe add that the reason the user doesn't get an indexing error is because indices of -1 and -2 will give the 1st and 2nd values starting from the end of the list.

Comment: @Green, and that's why he actually should be fine with `f.append(f[-1] + f[-2])` regardless of the range limits.

Comment: @bereal No, if you look at the 5th element of OP's output it's now based on the *wrong* positive index values to maintain the Fibonacci series, due to the offset by 2.  That's why it repeats "2, 3".

Comment: @pjs `f[-1] + f[-2]` sums the two last elements.

Comment: @bereal I understand that.  Now consider what happens after a few iterations when you have more than 2 elements, and you begin accessing positive indices using the `range` statement. It repeats summing the first couple of elements.  **That's** why it incorrectly repeats "2, 3, 2, 3".

Comment: @pjs Could you name `i` after which `f[-1] + f[-2]` starts accessing positive indices?

Comment: @pjs I perfectly understood what you meant before the first comment. `f.append(f[-1] + f[-2])` is still correct. It doesn't even refer to `i`.

Comment: @bereal The first two individual results that get generated are correct.  As an algorithm it's incorrect because the result is not a correct Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @pjs Kindly run the code `>`[here](https://repl.it/INiG)`<`. The code I am talking about is not the same as OP has.

Comment: @bereal Yes, that works and is a valid alternate solution for generating Fibonacci series.  You could post it as your own answer.  However, I was trying to explain to OP where *his* bug comes from.

Answer (score 2):

```
f=[1,1]

for i in range(8):
    f.append(f[i]+f[i+1])

print(f)
```

**RESULT**

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Comment: @Chaitanya Patil  your >> f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2])<< I have changed the f[i-2] -> f[i+1]

Answer (score 1):

```
f=[1,1]
for i in range(8):
    s=len(f)
    f.append(f[s-1]+f[s-2]) #sum of last two elements

print(f)
```

or use -1 and -2 as index for two last element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) function starts at 0 if you don't explicitly specify a starting point. In your case, it should be: `for i in range(2, 8)`.

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Also, in Python, you can use negative index in an array to count from the right instead of the left, this is why you had this weird result.

Comment: Thanq :-) got it

Answer (score 0):

Adding to pjs' answer: When `i = 0`, you are adding `f[-1]` and `f[-2]`, where an index of `-1` gives you the last element in the list and so on.

To fix that, as other answers have already pointed out, you need to set the correct starting point for `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Script

```
f=[1,1]

for i in range(2,8):
  print(i)
  f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2])
  print(f)
```

Output

```
2
[1, 1, 2]
3
[1, 1, 2, 3]
4
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
5
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
6
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
7
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Issue is `i` starts from 0,  `f[-1], f[-2]` returns 0.
start using range from 2 and 8 represents first 8 fibonacci numbers.

removing debug print

Script

```
f=[1,1]

for i in range(2,8):
   f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2])
print(f)
```

Comment: Thanks ! got it :-)